# Ajaxcontrol Toolkit CascadingDropdownList populated event trouble

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've got 2 `CascadingDropdownList`, *Application* and *Role*. When Application changes Role is populated. 
I do a partial rendering of a `UpdatePanel` with *User List* when *Application* or *Role* changes.

The problem is that when *Application* changes the value of *Role* sent in the `POST` to render `UpdatePanel` is the old *Role* value before Role is populated whih the list of roles of the new *emphasized text*selected *Application*.

So, the solution I am trying is to do the partial rendering after *Role* is populated. I remove *Application* trigger from the `UpdatePanel` and launch a postback by hand using `populated` event in *Role* `CascadeDropDownList`.

This way, when *Application* changes, *Role* is populated and (thanks to the event) `UpdatePanel` is updated. When *Role* changes the basic trigger in `UpdatePanel` makes the updated.

Code Behind:

```
ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType,"wireEvents","Sys.Application.add_load(addPopulatedEvent);", True)
```

HTML:

```
 <script>

   function updatePanel() {  __doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', null); }
   function addPopulatedEvent(sender, args) {if (!args.get_isPartialLoad()) { $find('<%=cmbRoles_CascadingDropDown.ClientID %>').add_populated(updatePanel); }  }

  </script>
```

And another problem raises. I can see in firebug network how the partial rendering `POST` launch at the same time, sometimes even before, that the populate roles `POST`. And still see the old 'pre-populated' value of Role in the partial rendering `POST`. In a few words: `CascadingDropdownList populated event` does not rise after the CascadingDropdownList is populated. It is weird because the event verb is in past form and a `populating event` also exist. So everything tells me that `populated event` should rise after Role is filled with the new data. But not.

2 Questions:

1. Am I doing something wrong about CascadingDropDownList events?
2. In the case my solution could not never work, could you point me to another working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a real bug. Fixed in v15.1.3 version. [Here](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27844) is the issue report.